# What does "T perfect" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the English  biographical movie: *Bronson* Paul says Bronson will be a good name for Michael Peterson.

> Paul: You're more the [Charles Bronson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Bronson) type.
>
> Peterson: Charles Bronson...
>
> Paul:Yes... "[Death Wish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Wish_(film))". Fits you down to a **T perfect**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two embedded phrases here.

**It fits you** means *it is the right size or shape for you* ([Cambridge dictionary online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fit)). In the quote it is used for a name and not a piece of clothes, which is quite possible of course.

**down to a T** (which is sometimes just **to a T**) means *perfectly*. See [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_a_T).

We could say there is a redundancy in saying "Fits you down to a T perfect" since "to a T" means perfectly.

Note that to be entirely correct it should be "it fits you perfectly" since *perfect* is an adjective and *perfectly* is an adverb, and to modify a verb grammar books say we must use an adverb. If it is "a mistake" then it is a very common mistake among native speakers. There is question about this on ELU: ["Something worked perfectly” vs “something worked perfect”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76214/12918).

The origin of "to a T" is uncertain. We can read about it in the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/to-a-t.html).

Comment: +1 There's actually two sentences there. It's "Fits you down to a T. Perfect!"

Comment: @AraucariaMan If I'd known some punctuation was missing from the quote I wouldn't have answered, OP could/should  have worked it out on his own with a dictionary. Well, never mind. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but our OP wouldn't be able to tell the punctuation from the film audio, so your post was very helpful :)